# Как правильно сделать управление

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю банальную 2д игру про танки . Нужно правильно реализовать управленеи  W,S - Движение вперед назад ПО ПРЯМОЙ КУДА СМОТРИТ ОБЪЕКТ. A,D - повороты. Искал в интернете и не смог найти как это вообще сделать. Почти везде пишут про transform.forward но у меня он всегда возвращает 0, 0, 1 как бы не вертел. Как это исправить или как сделать другое управление.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здесь за вас скрипт не напишут. Выкладывайте свой код в вопрос, который не работает, тогда можно будет что-то придумать.

Comment: @aepot а если все что у меня есть это движение вверх вниз все равно выложить?

Comment: чисто в теории https://answers.unity.com/questions/781012/move-object-relative-to-its-axis.html

Comment: transform.forward должен работать. Убедитесь, что используете Transform нужного объекта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На крайняк можно воспользоваться тригонометрией. Если знать угол поворота танчика, то можно высчитать его следующие координаты по следующим формулам: x = speed * sin(90 - transform.rotation.z) y = speed * cos(90 - transform.rotation.z). Возможно, придется преобразовывать градусы в радианы. С этим, думаю, справитесь и сами.